# Text background colour cuts to shape and length of text

Tags: html, css

is it possible to make the background colour of a line of text fit to the edge of the text itself?

Here is a visual example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[CSS cut in text http://www.blinkblink.co.uk/example.jpg](http://www.blinkblink.co.uk/example.jpg)

The text is a `<h3>` inside a `<div>` and at present all I can achieve is a square block background.

Comment: can you include a picture of what your background looks like right now, and the CSS you used to achieve it?

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle with your current HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, set the display property of the h3 element to inline. You may also need to adjust the line-height property to match the font size.

```
display:inline;
font-size:20px;
line-height:20px;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CuA4A/)**

Comment: Thanks! I had a float in there which once removed worked a treat with display:in-line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get something like to cover whole of the text! You can use this:

```
<div>
 <h3>Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan</h3>
</div>
```

And do this:

```
div {
 background-color: #hexcode;
}
```

Secondly, if you want only the text to be wrapped, then you can try to remove the `padding:` or `margin:` Even if you don't have any, still write this:

```
h3 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

This way, all of the padding or margins will be removed and the background will be provided on just the text!

This second one will fit perfect for your question: "make the background colour of a line of text fit to the edge of the text itself?"